# limit is not working in subquery

Tags: mysql

I have saved vehicle types in 'vehicle_types_locales', drivers in 'drivers' and driver's current location in 'drivercurrentlocation' table.

Logic : I am trying to get all vehicle types from main query then trying to select 5 drivers for each category from driver's tables which satisfying conditions as implemented. If records are less than 5 for all categories then it's working fine else it returns all driver's exist in category.(seems limit not working)

My query is :

```
SELECT vtl.vehicle_type_id as id ,vtl.name, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat(
        drv.id,'----', drv.firstname, '----', ifnull(drv.lastname,''), '----', 
        dll.latitude, '----', dll.longitude) SEPARATOR '--++--')
    FROM drivercurrentlocation as dll LEFT JOIN drivers as drv ON 
    (dll.driverid = drv.id) WHERE drv.active_vehicle_id > 0 AND 
    current_duty_status='F' and drv.status='A' and drv.onduty='Y' AND 
    drv.vehicle_type_id= vtl.vehicle_type_id AND latitude > '". 
    $latLongData['minLat']."' AND latitude < '". $latLongData['maxLat'] ."' 
    AND longitude > '". $latLongData['minLng'] ."' AND longitude < '". 
    $latLongData['maxLng']."' limit 5) 
as ddata FROM vehicle_types_locales 
WHERE vtl.status  = 'A' AND vtl.language_id = '$languageid'";
```

Please help me to resolve this limit issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change from `LIMIT 5` to `LIMIT 0,5`. This is the right way to limit data in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Note:Limit condition will not work when you use Group_concat.
To achieve limit put a subquery and limit the rows somewhat like this

```
SELECT vtl.vehicle_type_id as id ,vtl.name, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat(
        newdrv.id,'----', newdrv.firstname, '----', ifnull(newdrv.lastname,''), '----', 
        newdrv.latitude, '----', newdrv.longitude) SEPARATOR '--++--') from           (select drv.id, drv.firstname, ifnull(drv.lastname,''), 
        dll.latitude,dll.longitude
    FROM drivercurrentlocation as dll LEFT JOIN drivers as drv ON 
    (dll.driverid = drv.id) WHERE drv.active_vehicle_id > 0 AND 
    current_duty_status='F' and drv.status='A' and drv.onduty='Y' AND 
    drv.vehicle_type_id= vtl.vehicle_type_id AND latitude > '". 
    $latLongData['minLat']."' AND latitude < '". $latLongData['maxLat'] ."' 
    AND longitude > '". $latLongData['minLng'] ."' AND longitude < '". 
    $latLongData['maxLng']."' limit 5) newdrv ) 
as ddata FROM vehicle_types_locales 
WHERE vtl.status  = 'A' AND vtl.language_id = '$languageid'";
```

Answer (score 0):

After investing lots of hours, I have found a solution.

```
SELECT vtl.vehicle_type_id as id ,vtl.name, (
    SELECT substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(drv.id,'----
    ',drv.firstname, '----', ifnull(drv.lastname,''), '----', dll.latitude, 
    '----', dll.longitude) SEPARATOR '--++--'),'--++--',$no_of_drivers) 
    FROM drivercurrentlocation as dll LEFT JOIN drivers as drv ON 
    (dll.driverid = drv.id) WHERE drv.active_vehicle_id > 0 AND 
    current_duty_status='F' and drv.status='A' and drv.onduty='Y' AND 
    drv.vehicle_type_id= vtl.vehicle_type_id AND latitude > '". 
    $latLongData['minLat']."' AND latitude < '". $latLongData['maxLat']
    ."' AND longitude > '". $latLongData['minLng'] ."' AND longitude < '". 
    $latLongData['maxLng']."' ) 
as ddata FROM vehicle_types_locales as vtl 
WHERE vtl.status  = 'A' AND vtl.language_id = '$languageid'";
```

with this query I have found desired output.

Thanks for your answers.